# Using S3 Storage with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS.Net to upload user content (images) and display them on my site. This is what my code looks like currently for the upload:

```
using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client())
    {
        var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {

            BucketName = bucketName,
            InputStream = fileStream,
            Key = fileName,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
            //MD5Digest = md5Base64,
            //GenerateMD5Digest = true,
            Timeout = 3600000 //1 Hour
        };

        S3Response response = client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
        response.Dispose();
}
```

**Whats the best way to store the path to these files? Is there a way to get a link to my file from the response?**

Currently I just have a URL in my webconfig like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/<MyBucketName>/` and then when I need to show an image I take that string and use the key from the object I store in the db that represents the file uploaded.
**Is there a better way to do this?**

All the examples that come with it don't really address this kind of usage.  And the documentation isn't online and I don't know how to get to it after I install the SDK, despite following the directions on Amazon.

Comment: Just a +1 for the code sample! S3 / SDK appear to default to private files on upload, regardless of the bucket default. All the other examples I found that explicitly set the permissions used the transfer utility. An input stream is just what I was after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of storing paths including your bucket names in web.config is the same thing that I do, which works great. I then just store the relative paths in various database tables.

The nice thing about this approach is that it makes it easier to migrate to different storage mechanisms or CDNs such as CloudFront. I don't think that there's a better way than this approach because S3 files reside on a different domain, or subdomain if you do CNAME mapping, and thus your .NET runtime does not run under the same domain or subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a "Location" property in the response which points directly to the uri where the S3Object is.